# Can Google Docs converted .ppt files be reverted

Tags: google, google-drive, document-management, online-storage

After uploading a .ppt file onto Google Docs (and converted),

How am I able to "unconvert" it (retrieve the original version) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it is possible to "unconvert" and retrieve the original version in Google Docs.

You can download the Google Docs file as PowerPoint but this will cause another conversion from Google Docs back to PowerPoint.